# How to calculate the page index in grid view

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using a set of codes for all web pages

```
grvcity.PageIndex + = 1;
```

to get the next page in grid view

I want to caluclate the page index where the currently is on . How to do it

Comment: grvcity.PageIndex *is* the page it is currently on.  What are we missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridView.PageIndex property both gets and sets the index of currently displayed page:

```
[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
public virtual int PageIndex { get; set; }
```

Therefore, the answer in your case should simply be:

```
int currentPage = grvcity.PageIndex;
```

**Update**

If you are talking about the PageIndexChanging event, here is a sample:

```
protected void grvcity_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
grvcity.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
grvcity.DataBind();
}
```